# Debugging Excel Add-In with Javascript API

Tags: javascript, c#, excel, debugging, excel-addins

I am trying to debug an Excel Add-in written using the Office javascript API in VS 2015. (it is this example: https://github.com/OfficeDev/OData-Excel-Integration-Add-In-Sample).

When trying to set breakpoints in the C# bits of the code, it tells me that symbols are not loaded. Does anyone know how to enable debugging of C# in javascript Excel Add-Ins?

Comment: Have you tried building the source for the C# application and checking if any pdb (symbol) files are generated? These should contain the information you need to debug.

Comment: yes, pdbs are generated. my impression is that the debugger is attached to Excel rather than the web server where the C# code is running.